# Relation between areas in a trapezoyd

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, area, fractions, quadrilateral

A trapezoid of ABCD vertices is inscribed in a circle, with radius R, being AB = R and CD = 2R and BC and AD being non-parallel sides. The bisectors of the internal trapezoidal angles, so that the bisector of Â intercepts that of Dˆ at point Q, that of B intersects that of C N at point N and that of C ˆ intercepts that of Dˆ at point M. Knowing that the points M, N and Q are inside the ABCD trapezoid and that point P is the intersection of the Bˆ and Aˆ guidelines, determine the relationship between the areas of the MNPQ and ABCD polygons. Ans .: 1/9.
[image: my draw]

I tried a lot to do this, but everytime I found a segment with negative size 
Please, can someone help me?
Thanks for antetion.

Comment: The drawing seems to not to correspont to the text, as $Q$ is the intersection bisectors of $A$ and $C$ on the drawing, not $A$ and $D$ as in the text, the rest points similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint.

$CD$ is a diameter of the circle, which gives $AB=AD=BC=R$.

Comment: AD=BC=3R/2, no?

Comment: No! Try to understand, why.

Comment: I understood! Thanks for help me!